# Fb login button doesnt work with localhost

Tags: reactjs, localhost, facebook-javascript-sdk

i started a very simple project but the core of it is to use fb login button to gather fb users info. The problem is that I have tried all possible coptions, changing localhost in host file etc. It seems that facebook does not want us to use localhost for some reason as every single url must have https enabled.

Adding localhost to the domain and other options I am still getting this error:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to
>   this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

I have tested on my firebase with https link and it works fine, but to develop anything on live server is going to be a nightmare, especially when I am creating with react.

Is it even possible these days to use full fb api on localhost?

**EDITED**

To clear things up. I have my test app setup like this:

- **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs:** https://localhost:3000/ <- fb will add https automatically and wont save anything else
- **Site URL:** http://localhost:3000/
- **App domain:** localhost or http://localhost/ or http://localhost:3000/ same stuff

Answer (score -2):

- go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Select your app
- add http://localhost:port to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

**Or**

1.) In the developer.facebook.com, click on App.

2) Under settings in the "APP Domain" add localhost.

3) Click on "Add Platform" and choose "Website".

4) In the input box for site url  add 
`http://localhost:portNumber/`
  (whatever port number is applicable example 
`http://localhost:9000/`
 for play framework)

5.) Save the changes, the Fb login should work on your localhost now.

**Or**

Start webpack dev server with https enabled

```
devServer: {
  https:true
  },
```

More info here [Webpack https](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https)

Comment: I saw this answer in a different post, but that will not work as fb will add this with https instead of http. I have tried this already